# Logcat not showing correct logs for my Galaxy S4

Tags: android, eclipse, logcat

When I plug my S4 in and run eclipse, the logcat only displays logs from AndroidRuntime, dalvikvm, and Xposed Framework, but nothing else. There is no system messages, no errors, but more importantly, there is no output from any app, including mine. I downloaded a logcat viewing app on the phone and it read the logs just fine, but for some reason eclipse will not. I've reinstalled all the phone drivers and eclipse, as well as the android sdk. My nexus 7 and Transformer Infinity log just fine through eclipse. I can't figure out what's wrong with my S4.

It is rooted and has xposed installed, that is all.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same problem.
after long hours of reading and research, it seems that if you have a S4 running Android 4.3 - you might encounter Logcat problems. The reason is still unknown (to me, anyhow).

My S4 is rooted too, and I have a custom ROM installed running 4.3. 
When the Logcat stopped working, I spent hours reading almost everywhere possible, and I found a post recommending to downgrade to earlier Android version.
So I installed 4.2.2 and everything worked fine.

Hope this will help you...
Cheers!